# htop showing process time in red

Tags: python

I am checking the progress of python script I ran, I checked the process ID for it in `top` and it is there, but without CPU usage (when running it usually takes 20%). so I checked the `htop` for it and its time is displayed in red [image: server htop].

I ran the command using `nohup python conc.py&` no errors are showing in the log (nohup.out file).

My question is, how can I know that the script is actually running and haven't halted somewhere.

I also checked the `dmesg` for any info but nothing relating to the script, any help is appreciated.